# Check if string can be made by joining smaller strings

Tags: c, algorithm

How do I check if a string can be made entirely by concatenating 'n' other strings, where *n* is a variable?

Ex:

`catdogmice` is made of the strings `cat`, `dog` and `mice`
but `catdogmices` is not

**Edit1:** Here is a code I wrote (Sorry, I have no ground in coding and make pretty bad codes and it's giving a seg fault)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char words[1001][11];
char* str;
int flag;
void autopsy(char* str, int m)
{

        if(strcmp(str,'\0')==0)
                flag = 1;
        int len, i;
        for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
                len = strlen(words[i]);
                if(strncmp(words[i], str, len)==0)
                {
                        *str += len;
                        autopsy(str, m);
                }
        }
        if(flag == 1)
                printf("YES\n");
        else
                printf("NO\n");
}

int main()
{
        int m, l, i;
        scanf("%d %d", &m, &l);
        for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
                scanf("%s", words[i]);
        int t;
        scanf("%d", &t);
        while(t--)
        {
                flag = 0;
                gets(str);
                autopsy(str, m);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Here first I read the number of smaller words and the max length of the smaller words. Then the number of larger strings I'm accepting for checking and then I output if it can be formed or not. How can I make sure that if the large word is **catsdog** and my words are **cat**, **cats** and **dog**, then first **cat** is removed and then **sdog** cant be removed and answer is given as no, but actual answer is yes.

**Edit2**: Is it possible to solve with the data structure TRIE?

Comment: Are the strings always concatenated in order, as in your example? Or could "cat, dog and mice" also result in "micedogcat"?

Comment: Can smaller strings be reused, i.e. is it valid to form "catdogdogmice" or "catdogcatmice" out of cat, dog, mice? Also, is it legal to not use some smaller strings, i.e. can "catdog" be formed of cat, dog, mice?

Comment: secretstuff, It would be nice if you could answer the questions. It's an interesting problem but the answers differ a lot with the problem details.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Yes, smaller strings can be reused as many times as needed. And its legal to not use some strings too.

Comment: @PeterSchneider No, the strings can be used in any order.

Comment: Ah. The problem just got more complex :-).

Comment: @PeterSchneider Sorry about that :P, actually I am a high school student and am currently looking at elementary questions(for humans) like this and trying to figure out how it can be coded..

Comment: `if(strcmp(str,'\0')==0)` is a problem.  MAybe `if(*str == '\0')` was meant?

Answer (score 6):

NOTE: this solutions assumes you are allowed to use the words more than once.

You can do that using a [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach. Define the subproblem as "can the suffix of the initial string starting at position i be composed from the given strings". The DP will be one dimensional, thus I will assume you store subproblem results in an array dp of size n(where n is the size of the initial string). In eaech cell store a single flag- is it possible to form the given suffix or not.

Now to solve the problem for a given index i, you do the following -  iterate over all the words and for each word w<sub>j</sub> if w<sub>j</sub> is a prefix of the suffix of the initial string that starts on position i, then set dp[i] to 1 if dp[i + len(w<sub>j</sub>)] is 1.

To make it easier to understand. Say we have the string s<sub>0</sub>s<sub>0</sub>s<sub>1</sub>...s<sub>i</sub>s<sub>i+1</sub>...s<sub>n</sub>. To compute dp[i], iterate over all words. Say we are currently on word w<sub>j</sub> if w<sub>j</sub> is not a prefix of s<sub>i</sub>s<sub>i+1</sub>...s<sub>n</sub>(i.e. w<sub>j</sub>[0]==s<sub>i</sub>, w<sub>j</sub>[1 ]==s<sub>i+1</sub> and so on) do nothing. Otherwise check if dp[i + strlen(w<sub>j</sub>)] if it is one, then set dp[i] to 1 and stop the iteration over other words.

The approach will have linear memory overhead and its computational complexity will be in the order of n * m * max_word_len where m is the number of words and max_word_len is the maximum allowed word length.

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure but wouldn't you find words "ken", "do", "kendo" in the string "dokenkendo" in the wrong order? I.e. "do" would match the end, "ken" the one before, and then "kendo" would not match. The short ones which must be used in the beginning are used up because they match in the end.

Comment: The DP implies backtrack with memoization. My solution tries all possible paths, thus the complexity.

Comment: Hm. A single flag "it's possible to construct the substring from here" may not be enough because there can be more than one way, as I showed int he "dokenkendo" example. If you construct the ..."kendo" suffix with "ken" and "do" and thus cannot construct the prefix "doken"... with the remaining word "kendo", how do you backtrack? One would have to have a more complex "memorization structure" which actually finds all possible combinations to construct the substring and then tries to start with each one until they fail (or not, hooray). Oh, and then *none* of them may be correct, too!

Comment: I have a single flag for each position thus I have an additional array of flags dp of size n. This is always possible. However I think I understand what you say. My solutions assumes that you are allowed to use each string more than once. If that is not the case, more information will need to be added to the DP state.

Comment: Hmm, it was my mistake, sorry, wrong triangle accidentally pressed. But now I can't correct -"Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited"

Comment: @MBo done. Maybe someone asked on meta what to do in such cases

Answer (score 1):

If a string can be made by joining smaller strings, at least one of the smaller strings must be a prefix of the larger string. For each matching prefix, strip it from the input string and recurse. I there's no prefix and the remaining input string is empty, you found a solution.

Comment: This can be optimized by adding memoizations - don't recurse on suffixes you've already checked and this is the idea in my answer

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev My solution is based on the premise that it's legal to use smaller strings multiple times, e.g 'catcatdog' can be formed from 'cat' and 'dog'.

Comment: Same is mine. What I mean here by memoization is to avoid solving the problem after stripping the same part imagine this test "somestringmanyotherletters..." imagine the test among other string contains `so`, `me` and `some`. Your approach would check if you can form  "stringmanyotherletters..." twice - once for `so` and `me` and once for `some`. When you check if a given suffix can be formed you can memoize the result avoiding to do the same work twice

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I see - yes, you could trade memory vs. CPU time here.

Comment: I think you must add that the *longest* matching word must be chosen, or you can end up with short matches which you would need later.

Comment: @PeterSchneider All matching words should be chosen, since there may be multiple solutions. The algorithm traverses a tree of solutions.

Comment: True, you recurse for every match. That is unnecessary if only a "yes" or "no" is required as in the OP ("check whether").

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Sure, if you want to know whether there's *any* solution, you could simply terminate the recursion (e.g. via the return value of the function).

Answer (score 0):

Ivaylo Strandjev answer is more efficiency and cleaner than mine answer.

If you want make it simple you can use a dictionary (hashed) and see if at position 0 to end of string for sum of char  you can find a answer in the dictionary. if you find one you start a new sum of char at the position i where you are ton the end of string. but the complexity if minimal and maximal of n.

Comment: please note that the answer order may change I think it is fine to say if efficiency is not important...

Comment: By the way your answer is still not complete. What will happen if several strings match the last characters?

Comment: It's why I talk about a hash if it's not exactly the same word you can't match it. If it's not word that doesn't match and with a limited words in dictionary it's easy to avoid collisions.

Comment: That is not what I mean - if multiple words are suffix of the original string, you will have to explore several options to make sure the string can not be formed. In the end you will end up with a solution quite close to the one I propose

Comment: Ok don't uderstand that.. Yes in fact It's why I noticed you answer is more efficient and cleanest that mine. For this answer I talk just about the easy way to implement it not really about efficiency.
And we don't have details about which case he want use it so I give the most simple  way to do it with his example and limited words.

Comment: I understand you are not talking about efficiency but I am talking about accuracy here. Take this example: `somestring` and the words are `so`, `some`, `ring`, `string`. What would the algorithm you propose do?

Comment: Continued the sum until dictionary give answer and back with a kind of recurrence. But I agree my answer is not complete. And As I said "And we don't have details about which case he want use it so I give the most simple way to do it with his example and limited words "  then a trivial case.